# Script in python to download email attachments

Tags: python, email, outlook

I have the following script :

```
import imaplib
import email
import os

svdir = 'c:/downloads'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4('https://outlook.office365.com/mapi/emsmdb/?'
                     'MailboxId=6ebd46ee-55df-452e-a0af-44e7b248d992@jmawireless.com')
mail.login("RNa", "RN!")
mail.select("ADP Files")

typ, msgs = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "ADP Files")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    m = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        if filename is not None:
            sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, filename)
            if not os.path.isfile(sv_path):
                print(sv_path)
                fp = open(sv_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

The error being produced is:

```
C:\Users\rnandipati\Desktop\Batch Files\EMAIL ADP>email.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\idna.py", line 165, in encode
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long") UnicodeError: label empty or too long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\rnandipati\Desktop\Batch Files\EMAIL ADP\email.py", line 2, in <module>
        import email
    File "C:\Users\rnandipati\Desktop\Batch Files\EMAIL ADP\email.py", line 8, in <module>
        mail=imaplib.IMAP4( 'https://outlook.office365.com/mapi/emsmdb/?MailboxId=6ebd46ee-55df-452e-a0af-44e7b248d992@jmawireless.com')
    File "C:\Python34\lib\imaplib.py", line 181, in __init__
        self.open(host, port)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\imaplib.py", line 257, in open
        self.sock = self._create_socket()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\imaplib.py", line 247, in _create_socket
        return socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port))
    File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 494, in create_connection
        for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or to o long)
```

I do not know why is this error produced. I am fairly new to this kind of scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (and the source code too), the constructor [`imaplib.IMAP4()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imaplib.html) takes two parameters: *host*: the host name (usually a server name or IP address), defaulting to "localhost", and *port*: the port number, defaulting to the standard IMAP4 port).

Here, you are using an URL, which is wrong.

Try to open a connection like this:

```
with imaplib.IMAP4("outlook.office365.com") as imap4:
    ...
```

Consult this page to have the connection settings for Office 360: [POP and IMAP settings for Outlook Office 365 for business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c)

You may need SSL connection for Outlook Office 365. Here is a more useful usage example:

```
import imaplib

username = 'user@example.com'
password = 'password'

with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com') as imap4:
    imap4.login(username, password)

    # retrieve a list of the mailboxes and select one
    result, mailboxes = imap4.list()
    imap4.select("inbox")
```

**EDIT: alternative without `with` statement**

```
try:
    imap4.login(username, password)

    # retrieve a list of the mailboxes and select one
    result, mailboxes = imap4.list()
    imap4.select("inbox")

finally:
    imap4.close()
```

Comment: when I connect using SSL it shows me attributeerror : ___exit___.. @Laurent LAPORTE

Comment: You certainly use Python 2. Don't use the **with** statement.

Comment: I am using python 3.4 @Laurent LAPORTE

Comment: The imap4.close() shows an error:

command close illegal in state NONAUTH only allowed in states SELECTED.

Comment: Hello, i have been able to connect to the server. I have also been able to get the mails and print them (which prints in an encoded format). 

There is an error on the line `m = email.message_from_string(email_body)`  `that says initial value must be str or none, not bytes`. 

Can you help?

Comment: @Rahul: You should post another question, because it becomes confusing...

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895434/script-to-download-email-attachments` I have please have a look. Thanks @LaurentLAPORTE

Answer (score 0):

```
import imaplib
import email
import os

server = 'outlook.office365.com'
user = 'YOUR USERNAME'
password = 'YOUR PASSWORD'
outputdir = 'DIRECTORY THAT YOU WANT FILES DOWNLOADED TO'
subject = 'Data Exports' #subject line of the emails you want to download attachments from

# connects to email client through IMAP
def connect(server, user, password):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    m.login(user, password)
    m.select()
    return m

# downloads attachment for an email id, which is a unique identifier for an
# email, which is obtained through the msg object in imaplib, see below 
# subjectQuery function. 'emailid' is a variable in the msg object class.

def downloaAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir):
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(BODY.PEEK[])")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        return
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None:
            open(outputdir + '/' + part.get_filename(), 'wb').write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

# download attachments from all emails with a specified subject line
# as touched upon above, a search query is executed with a subject filter,
# a list of msg objects are returned in msgs, and then looped through to 
# obtain the emailid variable, which is then passed through to the above 
# downloadAttachmentsinEmail function

def subjectQuery(subject):
    m = connect(server, user, password)
    m.select("Inbox")
    typ, msgs = m.search(None, '(SUBJECT "' + subject + '")')
    msgs = msgs[0].split()
    for emailid in msgs:
        downloaAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir)

subjectQuery(subject)
```

Comment: I added some additional comments to help, but the code is self explanatory if one takes the time to read the documentation in imaplib and go through the functions. People that are just looking for code on here to copy and paste will never learn anything. Appreciate your feedback though. Hopefully it makes more sense now with the additional comments.

Comment: I think you weren't selected because you didn't address the issue.  They weren't asking for code that they could just copy and paste.  They said, "I do not know why is this error produced. I am fairly new to this kind of scripting."

Ironically enough, you posted a complete code solution and then complained that people just want to copy code.  Instead, you could have addressed the issue / question, which didn't require anything you offered.

Pardon if I sound blunt.  Just giving my take since it sounds like you wanted feedback.