# script to download email attachments

Tags: python, outlook

i am facing an error at line 18 (m = email.message_from_string(email_body)) saying that `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`. When I try to run it by saying `print (data[0][1])` it gives me an output of the email in an encoded format.

I want to debug the error.

```
import imaplib
import email
import os

svdir = 'C:\\Users\\rnandipati\\Downloads'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com',993)
mail.login("rnaati@jess.com", "R!")
mail.select("Inbox")

typ, msgs = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "ADP Files")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")

    email_body = data[0][1]
    m = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        if filename is not None:
            sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, filename)
            if not os.path.isfile(sv_path):
                print(sv_path)
                fp = open(sv_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email` module includes a function `message_from_bytes`. Use that instead of `message_from_string` to parse a `bytes` object.

```
m = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
```

Comment: It doesn't show the error anymore, but it doesn't give the desired output either

Comment: I am trying to download attachments from an email that contains the subject as shown in the code. When i put `message_from_bytes` it just executes and shows nothing.

Comment: Well, I answered the question you asked and helped you debug (and fix) this error. If you get stuck again as you work on your program, **ask a new question**. If it's not too vague or too broad, someone will help you along.