# How to download outlook email attachments using python 3.4

Tags: python

I am trying to download the outlook email attachments using python 3.4, I have logged in outlook usingy Gmail credentials. Can I know how to get attachments from outlook.
Thanks in advance

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857002/script-in-python-to-download-email-attachments and this https://geekdudes.wordpress.com/2018/12/26/python-script-for-parsing-office-365-emails/

Comment: Also https://pyoutlook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyOutlook.html#pyOutlook.core.message.Message.attachments

Comment: Hi @saik how much experience do you have working with Python?

Comment: I am new to python real time projects @Tim McNamara

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import email, imaplib
import os
class FetchEmail():
    def __init__(self,
        mail_server="outlook.office365.com", 
        username="username@outlook.com",
        password="'password'"):

        self.error = None
        self.connection = None
        self.mail_server = mail_server
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(mail_server)
        self.connection.login(username, password)
        self.connection.select(readonly=False) # so we can mark mails as readread

    def close_connection(self):
          """
        Close the connection to the IMAP server
        """
          self.connection.close()

    def save_attachment(self, msg, download_folder="/tmp"):
        """
        Given a message, save its attachments to the specified
        download folder (default is /tmp)

        return: file path to attachment
        """
        att_path = "No attachment found."
        for part in msg.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue

            filename = part.get_filename()
            att_path = os.path.join(download_folder, filename)

            if not os.path.isfile(att_path):
                fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
        return att_path

    def fetch_unread_messages(self):
        """
        Retrieve unread messages
        """
        emails = []
        (result, messages) = self.connection.search(None, 'UnSeen')
        if result == "OK":
            for message in messages[0].split(' '):
                try: 
                    ret, data = self.connection.fetch(message,'(RFC822)')
                except:
                    print ("No new emails to read.")
                    self.close_connection()
                    exit()

                msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
                if isinstance(msg, str) == False:
                    emails.append(msg)
                response, data = self.connection.store(message, '+FLAGS','\\Seen')

            return emails

        self.error = "Failed to retreive emails."
        return emails


fe = FetchEmail()
```

you can see also these:[How to fetch an email body using imaplib in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230037/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-using-imaplib-in-python)
[Python Script for downloading new email attachments using imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892350/python-script-for-downloading-new-email-attachments-using-imap)